# C# Async function - using WhenAll function and await word together

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I need to understand something,
i have a function, for example:

```
public static class classExample
{
     public async Task funcAsync()
    {

        List<Task<string>> exampleList= new List<Task<string>>();
        // do stuff          
        await Task.WhenAll(exampleList);
    }
}
```

and in my main method i have:

```
 main()
 {
       classExample.funcAsync();         
 }
```

If i use await word in main like this:

```
await classExample.funcAsync();
```

is different from without await in main? i asking because i have

```
await Task.WhenAll(exampleList);
```

inside the function.

What the different?

And more question, i have this example:

```
async Task function2()
{
    // do stuff
    await //for some code will be done
}

main()
{
    function2();
    function3();
}
```

If i not use await word so the function will continue to function3,
in this case i not need that function3 waiting to function2 and this is
can to continue but the question: will the function2 do all the work?
in case function3 will end all the work before function2 will end.
after function3 will end all the work the main function wait to function2 will ended?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not `public static async Task funcAsync()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use await word in main like this: `await classExample.funcAsync();`
> is different from without await in main?

Yes, `funcAsync` returns a `Task` which will complete when all the `exampleList` `Task`s have completed (due to the use of `Task.WhenAll`), so without using `await`, your `Main` will likely exit before those have all completed.

In your second example, not awaiting `function2` will allow `function3` to execute without waiting for `function2` to complete, however, if `function3` completes before the `Task` returned from `function2` has completed, then your code will exit prematurely.

You can mitigate this by storing a reference to the `Task` and awaiting later:

```
var task = function2();
function3();
await task;
```

Or if `function3` also returns a `Task`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(function2(), function3());
```